# Rails routing, can't use #create action on nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes

I have this routes for user's payments

*config/routes.rb*

```
  resources  :users do
resources :payment_sources, only: [:index, :new, :create, :destroy], controller: 'users/payment_sources'
end
```

Running `rake routes | grep payment_source` gives me this:

```
        user_payment_sources GET      /users/:user_id/payment_sources(.:format)      users/payment_sources#index
                             POST     /users/:user_id/payment_sources(.:format)      users/payment_sources#create
     new_user_payment_source GET      /users/:user_id/payment_sources/new(.:format)  users/payment_sources#new
         user_payment_source DELETE   /users/:user_id/payment_sources/:id(.:format)  users/payment_sources#destroy
```

So I don't have a path or url helper... So I went ahead in my form and I wrote the url

*app/views/users/payment_sources/new.html.erb*

`<%= form_with(url: 'users/payment_sources#create' , id: "payment-form") do |form| %>`

This gives me back the error

`No route matches [POST] "/users/16/payment_sources/users/payment_sources"`

Clearly I did something wrong, I don't know what though. Any advice on this kind of nested resources stuff?

My controller code is:

*app/controllers/users/payments_sources_controller.rb**

```
class Users::PaymentSourcesController < ApplicationController

def new
end

def create
token = params[:stripeToken]

customer = Stripe::Customer.create({
  email: current_user.email,
  source: token,
})

payment = PaymentSource.create(
  user:           current_user,
  card_last4:     params[:card_last4],
  card_exp_month: params[:card_exp_month],
  card_exp_year:  params[:card_exp_year],
  card_brand:     params[:card_brand]
)

redirect_to root_path, notice: "Hurray, your debit card has been saved"
 end
end
```

How do I access my create action on PaymentSourcesController??

Comment: *So I don't have a path or url helper...* - what makes you say that? You have `user_payment_sources_path` (as shown in your `rake routes`). So, do `user_payment_sources_path(@user)`...

Comment: Yeah, sorrry... I meant for the create action. I forgot to specify. My bad

Comment: It's the same as `index`. Using the `user_payment_sources_path` in a form causes a `POST`, which then routes to the `create` action. The blank in front of `POST` just indicates that it's the same as the preceding path helper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following

```
<%= form_with(url: "/users/#{current_user.id}/payment_sources", 
              id: "payment-form", method: post) do |form| %>
```

OR

```
<%= form_with(url: user_payment_sources_path(user_id: current_user), 
              id: "payment-form", method: post) do |form| %>
```

Comment: God bless you mate, minor changes to your code, just in case this might be useful for someone else:  `<%= form_with(url: "/users/#{current_user.id}/payment_sources", id: "payment-form", method: :post) do |form| %>`

Comment: You'll want to add `@user` into that second construction (since `user_payment_sources_path` needs `user_id`), no? Also, is `method: post` necessary? Doesn't a form automatically post?

Comment: Yes it should be `user_payment_sources_path(user_id: current_user)`, didn't check though

Answer (score 1):

As you see, when you do rails route the url for create is user_payment_source. So in your form you should replace url like this
`<%= form_with(url: 'user_payment_sources_path' , id: "payment-form", method: "post") do |form| %>`

Comment: replace urls like what?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= form_with(url: user_payment_sources_url, id: "payment-form", method: "post") do |form| %>
```

Hope this help :)

Comment: Didn't work, I get `No route matches [POST] "/users/16/payment_sources/users/payment_sources"` error. I don't know why I'm getting that additional `users/payment_sources` to my url... My other routes seem fine, and they're all in the resource block :(